# Tron wallet integration in android application

Tags: android, cryptocurrency, trust, tron

I am developing a android application for TRON blockchain. I'm using Trust wallet library.

```
implementation 'com.trustwallet:wallet-core:2.3.9'
```

Sign transaction is almost done but for broadcasting I need `raw_data_hex`  data .How can I get it.

code

```
 val privateStr = "privatekey"
 val privateBytes: ByteArray = fromHexString(privateStr)
 val trc = Tron.TransferContract.newBuilder()
           .setOwnerAddress("owner_address")
           .setToAddress("toadress")
           .setAmount(1000000L)
 val transaction = Tron.Transaction.newBuilder()
                    .setTransfer(trc)
                    .build()

 val signingInput = Tron.SigningInput.newBuilder()
                    .setTransaction(transaction)
                    .setPrivateKey(ByteString.copyFrom(privateBytes))
 val output = AnySigner.sign(signingInput.build(), CoinType.TRON, Tron.SigningOutput.parser())
 println("*****signing_output${output.json}")
```

and output json is

```
{"raw_data":{"contract":[{"parameter":{"type_url":"type.googleapis.com/protocol.TransferContract","value":{"amount":1000000,"owner_address":"419c84ec90ef46e68530893cf3229a1dd695b8b457","to_address":"41105e58ce5d754034475f24149ab910f9602bc141"}},"type":"TransferContract"}],"expiration":1608078105411,"ref_block_bytes":"0000","ref_block_hash":"9afbf4c8996fb924","timestamp":1608042105411},"signature":["7204dd578e610164d415f30e57eeb07cab2028a82992c6986f932271796d14b810f85e7b634e0606eefcfe9c76a85663f68a076be8efe7f2355fdb2dc5986f2801"],"txID":"6f3027995c380950442a0f9479ccf31948c7d1134314e333d4b3688799f3d4d1"}
```

Comment: u got solution?